# Combine list of tuples into a single list using map

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, tuples

Imagine that we have a list of tuples such as:

```
List((5,4), (3,2), (1,0))
```

How would you multiply the values in each tuple with themselves then combine the products into a single list?

```
List(20, 6, 1)
```

I believe there is a way to do so using Scala's built-in map function, but I'm unsure of how to do so.

Comment: It is hard to make `1 * 0` to become `1` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val list = List((5,4), (3,2), (1,0))
list.map { case (a, b) => a * b }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. I didn't realize you could pattern match inside of a map.

Comment: @user3277752 You could also do `list.map(t => t._1 * t._2)`.